# Why are predicate and class distinct in rdf?

Tags: rdf

In RDF, a class is distinguished from a predicate or attribute. What is the benefit of doing this versus just having one thing, a class, that can appear as subject, predicate or object in any triple?

Edit: for example:

```
1 book has chapters
2 book1 is book
3 chapter1 is chapter
4a book1 chapter chapter1
```

In this example, chapter is both an object (in statement 3) and a predicate (in statement 4a). Some people claim that this is not a good idea.

The meaning of these statements is quite obvious - a book has chapters, book1 is a book, chapter1 is a chapter, book1 has a chapter called chapter1. An alternative suggested is to replace 4 above with 4b:

```
4b book1 has chapter1
```

However, this requires more effort to parse/reason: if book has chapter, book has author, book has publisher, then a statement like 
    book1 has foo
requires a lot more work to figure out (we have to find that foo is, say, an author to figure out that book1's author is foo). Better still, I can avoid statement 3 above, since statement 4 tells me that chapter1 is a chapter.

This pattern appears commonly in graphs containing both data and metadata. Are there any disadvantages in using 1,2,4a versus 1,2,3,4b? The only problem I see is that this violates the distinction between a property and a class (subject/object), but how does that affect us practically?

Answer (score 4):

Your example (books and chapters) only appears to make sense because of the loose and flexible way we use language, and our human interpretation (and your use of a possessive as the example)

So if I said

```
Book - Chapter - Chapter1
```

then that only *appears* to make sense because mentally we map the noun Chapter to the verb phrase "has Chapter", because we understand how books and chapters work. Machines consuming RDF do not understand this!

But if I said Book - Person - John, what are we to make of this? Is John the author, the reader, one of the characters, or what? This is why we need to specify an unambiguous predicate, e.g.

```
Book - hasAuthor - John

Book - readBy - John
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, in principle. Since the noun chapter and the verb 'has chapter' are different, they should be different. However, this also introduces an additional overhead of parsing the string to, say, find chapters in a book - I have to find triples with a predicate _containing_ the word chapter as opposed to looking for the whole word chapter. Isn't it practically more efficient to use the same word in a system that understands the two words to mean the same thing? In your example, I could use: Book has Author, and Book1 Is Book

Comment: Isn't it practically more efficient to use the same word in a system that understands the two words to mean the same thing? In your example, I could use: `Book has Author, Book1 Is Book, Author1 is Author, Book1 Author Author1` as long as I understand what that means. In a sense, English is more cumbersome in requiring a qualifier like 'has' to convert a class to a predicate.

Comment: In RDF it is conventional to use lowercase for predicates, and capitalised words for classes, so you could have the predicate "author" and the class "Author", I think. But you wouldn't normally query such data by string parsing - you would use a triplestore and query for triples with a specific predicate (or some more complex query expressed in a language such as SPARQL). It wouldn't really matter whether the predicate was "author" or "hasAuthor".

Comment: ...and as I mentioned in my answer, it's not about what _you_ can understand, but about what the data formally mean to a machine that understands RDF(S) semantics. Writing Book1-Author-Author1 doesn't make any sense within these semantics (if Author is an rdfs:Class), because it's instance-class-instance not instance-predicate-instance.

Comment: My question is exactly why that is so - what benefits led rdf designers to treating the predicate as distinct from subjects and objects? At a human language level, I understand the distinction is the same as nouns versus verbs. At a formal machine readable level, the URI provides enough to disambiguate one resource from another. Was it just a human language mimicking thing, or was it an additional constraint to enforce that a predicate is semantically different from a noun, or were there any practical benefits of enforcing this?

Comment: At the pure RDF level, a predicate is no different from a subject or object, in that and URI can be placed in any of the 3 'slots' of the triple.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3831/discussion-between-dna-and-anand)

Answer (score 3):

I don't entirely understand your question here.  The RDF data model is based upon three kinds of terms:

1. URIs (aka Named Resources) - These may appear in any position in the Triple
2. Blank Nodes (aka Anonymous Resources) - These may appear as the Subject/Object of a Triple
3. Literals - These may appear only as the Object of a Triple

When you start talking about classes you are no longer talking pure RDF as you are brining in a schema language like RDFS or OWL which define the notion of classes.  The main reason for using these higher level schema languages is that it allows you to define restrictions and relationships more clearly and perhaps use some reasoning over those.

Regardless of whether something is a Class the only restrictions on where it can appear in a triple are the term type.  So for example I could write the following:

```
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/> . 

ex:Thing a rdfs:Class .
ex:this ex:Thing ex:that .
```

That's perfectly legal RDF it just doesn't necessarily actually express data that makes any sense to anyone!

Comment: rdf:class represents a subject or object - I have heard that while a predicate may be treated as a class, the same thing cannot be used as a predicate and as a subject/object (my example and yours are frowned upon). The reason given in one book  (Thinking on the Web) is that some modelers may be confused. I want to understand exactly why this may be wrong, if at all.

Comment: Essentially because predicates are not classes! They are instances of rdf:Property. Both can sensibly be the subject or object of triples, so that you can make schema assertions about them and relate them to other classes or predicates, via subClassOf and subPropertyOf relations.

Comment: @DNA Only if we're talking RDFS, if we're talking pure RDF then there is no such thing as a class and a predicate is merely one term of the triple, the same value can occur as whatever term you wish provided it meets the term type restrictions of RDF.  Properties and Classes only become distinct when we start working at schema level

Comment: Agreed - but the original question (at least implicitly) involves classes, so that brings in the RDFS (or OWL) side of things...

Comment: @DNA Yes it does, just the impression I got was that the OP was something of a novice so I wanted to make clear that RDF on its own says nothing about classes